# Loading webgrid from drop down

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm newbie to MVC 3, Linq to SQL, I am trying to populate my WebGrid via data value being selected from drop down list but could get it right. Help.

Code:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        EmployeeAtdDataContext DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Precise Technology Consultants";

            //var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp();
            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
            ViewData["EmplID"] = new SelectList(names, "EmplID", "EmplName");
            return View(EmployeeAtd);

        }
```

View:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models

@Html.DropDownList("EmplID")
@{

    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, defaultSort: "EmplID");

}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

Now View is showing a filled dropdown list with names but I want that when I click any name from list than a webgrid should load records for that particular person, for that I have wrote a working query which loads on basis  of empID, so far I am passing NULL to that but want to load it by dropdown selected key

Comment: or what should i do ?